# What does it mean to set an Azure Admin when creating a SQL DB and which value do I select for admin?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have only just opened a trial account on Azure with free credit. I am trying to create my first DB. I am at the option where I need to create an authentication for the server. Out of curiosity I selected 'Use both SQL and Azure AD Authentication'. I need to select an Azure AD Admin. I'm not sure what is meant by this and what value I am supposed to select in the AD pane? Do I search for users?

[image: Screenshot of my screen]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually authenticate through server credentials , but when azure ad is also involved , we may need to set **one user** or **a group** as administrator , so that it is accessible only by them who has admin set for security purpose (like Multi factor authentication (server credentials +azure ad admin user or user ofadmin group)).

From [Azure Active Directory authentication - Azure SQL Database | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview#administrator-structure)
when using Azure AD authentication, there are two Administrator accounts:

- The original Azure SQL Database administrator (we created this
  account when creating a new service.)and
- The Azure AD administrator.

1. The Azure AD administrator who can access can be an Azure AD user or an Azure AD group.
   When the administrator is a group account, it can be used by any group member, enabling multiple Azure AD administrators for the server. Using group account enhances manageability by allowing you to centrally add and remove group members in Azure AD without changing the users or permissions in SQL Database or Azure Synapse

> Only the administrator based on an Azure AD account can create the
> first Azure AD contained database user in a user database.

[image]

2. Once we have provisioned the Azure SQL Server and its database, we need to configure who can access the database.
   you may need to give access ex: db_datareader, db_datawriter , db_ddladmin  etc individually to some users and to the Azure resources that need to query the database or read or make changes (you will have to assign these resources a managed identity before that). In short,  we need to grant SQL Database access to an Azure AD group.

If group is not already created , we need to create an Azure AD group, add users and managed identities that need access to the database and grant permissions to this group .

Or Search for the single user you want to set as the Azure AD admin for your Azure SQL server.

**References:**

1. [How to provision an Azure SQL Database with Active Directory
   authentication - DEV Community](https://dev.to/techwatching/how-to-provision-an-azure-sql-database-with-active-directory-authentication-7hm)
2. [Configure Azure Active Directory authentication - Azure SQL
   Database & SQL Managed Instance & Azure Synapse Analytics |
   Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell)
3. [Setup Azure SQL Server to use Azure Active Directory authentication
   option | by Thanh Le | Medium](https://letienthanh0212.medium.com/setup-azure-sql-server-to-useazure-active-directory-option-b90dccd9e277)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This information is really useful.